# Best way to do a dictionary search

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime

I've written a dynamic programming algorithm to solve a vehicle routing problem with time windows.  The goal is to find the cheapest way to assign locations to vehicles so that the vehicle arrives at each location inside a given time window.  I store the partial solutions that I generate in a dictionary with the format:

> {(set{locations visited}, tuple(current locations), tuple(current time), version):(tuple(costs), tuple(previous location), tuple(previous time), tuple(vehicle order), previous version)}

I was excited because the program seems to function correctly, but it's very slow.  When running the code on relatively small test cases (15 randomly generated locations) it's taking 280,000+ seconds.  As part of my code I include several functions to eliminate partial solutions that cannot be part of a feasible solution.  Two of these functions need to use a dictionary search to identify the fastest (or cheapest) way to visit a certain set of locations and end at certain locations.  To do this I use the dictionary search:

```
self.label_check = {k: v for k, v in self.memo.items() if k[0]==self.new_visited and k[1]==self.sorted_nlp}
```

I have a feeling this is my biggest time expenditure as the dictionary (memo) is 650,000+ items by the end of the program.

I was wondering, would I be better off creating a list of dictionaries based on the size of the set of locations visited?  When I do those dictionary searches the specific locations will change, but the number of locations will not.  For example if I'm considering adding the label {{1,2,3}, (1,2), (10,5), 1}.  I would want to search for any dictionaries keys with key[0] = {1,2,3} and key[1] = (1,2).  So I'd only need to search the dictionary keys where the locations visited have size 3.

My question is will this change create a significant time savings?

Comment: Can you please post your entire code, something that I can run on my end to see the problem ([MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example))? I'm having a hard time reconstructing what you're doing just by reading, maybe someone else can help.

Comment: Also instead of saying "I have a feeling this is my biggest time expenditure", you can use the Python profilers to get a definitive answer https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html

Comment: Boris, my full code exceeds the character limit for the message body ... so I can't really share what I've done.  Thank you for taking the time to try and help.  I'll try running a profiler and see if I can specifically identify the slow down.